# Preciso comparar variáveis com a falta de informação

Tags: javascript, if

Estou criando um formulário e preciso alertar o usuário quando um campo não está preenchido. Estou tentando usar o if para fazer essa comparação, já tentei comparar com o null e não funcionou.
meu código está assim:

```js
function Cadastrar(){

    var titulo = document.getElementById("titulo").value;
    var editora = document.getElementById("editora").value;
    var conteudoTabela = document.getElementById("livros_cadastrados");
    var novaLinha = document.createElement("tr");

    if(titulo == null || editora == null){
        alert("Dados incompletos");
    }else{
        novaLinha.innerHTML = "<td>" + titulo + "</td><td>" + editora + "</td><td><a href='' class='botaoExcluir'>Excluir</a>";
        conteudoTabela.appendChild(novaLinha);
        alert("Novo livro cadastrado:" + "\n" + titulo);
    }        
}
```

Sou bastante iniciante, portanto, se possível, gostaria de uma explicação bem detalhada.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Onde estás a chamar essa função `Cadastrar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, creio que você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

function Cadastrar(){

```
var titulo = document.getElementById("titulo").value;
var editora = document.getElementById("editora").value;
var conteudoTabela = document.getElementById("livros_cadastrados");
var novaLinha = document.createElement("tr");

if(titulo == '' || editora == ''){
    alert("Dados incompletos");
}else{
    novaLinha.innerHTML = "<td>" + titulo + "</td><td>" + editora + "</td><td><a href='' class='botaoExcluir'>Excluir</a>";
    conteudoTabela.appendChild(novaLinha);
    alert("Novo livro cadastrado:" + "\n" + titulo);
}
```

}

Se sua intenção é apenas verificar se os campos estão vazios, você utiliza a verificação por `''` pois é como você coloca a condição se o campo está vazio ou não. Deixar como nulo creio que não funciona ou se funcionar, não seria da melhor maneira. Irá depender um pouco também de como e onde você chama esta função, se for algo em `onsubmit` ou `onchange` até mesmo com `onblur` e `onfocusout`. Se for o caso, coloque seu código HTML também.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!